# How to aggregate arrays element by element in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, sum, aggregate-functions

In BigQquery how can I aggregate arrays element by element ?

For instance if I have this table

| id | array_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2, 3] |
| 2 | [4, 5, 6] |
| 3 | [7, 8, 9] |

I want to sum all the vector element-wise and output `[1+4+7, 2+5+8, 3+6+9] = [12, 15, 18]`

I can SUM float fields with `SELECT SUM(float_field) FROM table` but when I try to apply the SUM on an array I get

```
No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: ARRAY.
Supported signatures: SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64); SUM(NUMERIC); SUM(BIGNUMERIC) at [1:8]
```

I have found [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) in the doc but it is not what I want: it just creates an array from values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select array_agg(sum_val order by id) as res
from (
    select idx, sum(val) as sum_val
    from mytable t
    cross join unnest(t.array_value) as val with offset as idx
    group by idx
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select array_agg(val order by offset) 
from (
  select offset, sum(val) as val 
  from `project.dataset.table` t, 
  unnest(array_value) as val with offset 
  group by offset
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select array_agg(sum_val)
from (select (select sum(val)
              from unnest(t.array_value) val
             ) as sum_val
      from t
     ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

I think technically you simply refer to the individual values in the arrays using `offset()` or `safe_offset()` in case there might be missing values

```sql
-- example data
with temp as (
  select * from unnest([
    struct(1 as id, [1, 2, 3] as array_value),
    (2, [4,5,6]),
    (3, [7,8])
  ])
)

-- actual query
select
  [
    SUM( array_value[safe_offset(0)] ),
    SUM( array_value[safe_offset(1)] ),
    SUM( array_value[safe_offset(2)] )
  ] as result_array
from temp
```

I put them in a result array, but you don't have to do that. I had the last array missing one value to show that the query doesn't break. If you want it to break you should use `offset()` without the 'safe_'

Comment: How can I generalize that to big array, let's say with 1000 values ? I don't want to manually write the 1000 indices

Comment: I used spreadsheets to write these kind of queries-parts semi-automatically using formulas ;) Since you're basically using those array-entries as columns and SQL doesn't provide bulk- or aggregation-functions for across columns, only rows, I don't think it's possible to scale this up using SQL. You could also write your customized query-builder in python/etc. ...